# How to map SQL data into Java JSON object and JSON array?

Tags: java, mysql, json

I am working in Java to build JSON objects and want to send them into a JSON array all because of unsorted data into my database. I am not able to map the data into right format. I think I am lacking in logic.

Below is the image of my database table, which is in MySQL:

[image: this my table in data base]

What I want to create is a JSON format for this table which looks like this:

```
  [
  {
    "1": "450",
    "2": "495",
    "OUTLET": "TOTTAL2",
    "BILLDATE": "",
    "TOTAL": "945"
  },
  {
    "1": "10",
    "2": "15",
    "OUTLET": "Ol1",
    "BILLDATE": "08-21-2018",
    "TOTAL": "25"
  },
  {
    "1": "20",
    "2": "25",
    "OUTLET": "ol1",
    "BILLDATE": "08-22-2018",
    "TOTAL": "45"
  },
  {
    "1": "30",
    "2": "35",
    "OUTLET": "ol1",
    "BILLDATE": "08-23-2018",
    "TOTAL": "65"
  },
  {
    "1": "40",
    "2": "45",
    "OUTLET": "ol2",
    "BILLDATE": "08-21-2018",
    "TOTAL": "85"
  },
  {
    "1": "50",
    "2": "55",
    "OUTLET": "ol2",
    "BILLDATE": "08-22-18",
    "TOTAL": "105"
  },
  {
    "1": "60",
    "2": "65",
    "OUTLET": "ol2",
    "BILLDATE": "08-23-2018",
    "TOTAL": "125"
  },
  {
    "1": "70",
    "2": "75",
    "OUTLET": "ol3",
    "BILLDATE": "08-21-2018",
    "TOTAL": "145"
  },
  {
    "1": "80",
    "2": "85",
    "OUTLET": "ol3",
    "BILLDATE": "08-22-2018",
    "TOTAL": "165"
  },
  {
    "1": "90",
    "2": "95",
    "OUTLET": "ol3",
    "BILLDATE": "08-23-201818",
    "TOTAL": "185"
  }
]
```

The above JSON is my desired output. But I am not able to map the data in loop or I am not getting the logic. I just want to create a JSON format for the html table I have also provided the json that I want.

The place where I am lagging is in coding and thinking of logic that how could I loop the data to get desired format:

And this is the table which i want to make

[image]

I have knowledge of GSON in java to parse json (send json in Java) so I can do that the only thing I want is to like how can I code forth.

Here is my Java code code by which I am getting the first header

```
    String TotalAmountWithDateSql = "quwry1";
//          System.out.println("TotalAmountWithDateSql"+TotalAmountWithDateSql);
            String GrandTotalSql = "query2";
//          System.out.println("grandTotal"+GrandTotalSql);

            try {
                con = DBConnection.createConnection();
                statement = con.createStatement();

                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(GrandTotalSql);

                while (resultSet.next()) {

                    map.put("OUTLET/HOURS", "  ALL");
                    GrandTotal = resultSet.getLong("TOTAL");
                    map.put("TOTAL", GrandTotal);

                    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(TotalAmountWithDateSql);
                    while (resultSet.next())

                    {

                        BillTime = resultSet.getString("TIME");
                        NetAmtWithTime = resultSet.getLong("AMOUNT");
                        map.put(BillTime, NetAmtWithTime);
                    }
                    list.add(map);
                    str = gson.toJson(list);
                }
                System.out.println("value  " + str);
                response.setContentType("application/json");
                response.getWriter().write(str);
```

from this Java code I am getting

Now I want to call data below this like the JSON I have uploaded, but this is only giving me the first header:

[image: but this is only giving me the 1st header]

Comment: [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/), e.g. writing a `SELECT` statement, retrieve data using JDBC, JPA, or other means, manipulate the data into the desired form, generating JSON from some in-memory data structure. In short, as question currently stands, it is way **too broad**.

Comment: @Andreas i am using hash map from one query i am calling the outlets and storing them into list and running the next query on the size of that 1st query to get dates but  i am not able to loop them into {}.

Comment: Don't try to explain in text in a comment. **Edit** the question, explain there *and* show the code you do have and explain where *specifically* you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple indeed. You need to fetch all records and create a list which contains map object where each map object will contain those five key value pairs that you want.

Following is the kind of code you will need to write,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    createJson();
}

public static List<Map<String, String>> getMapList(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    List<Map<String, String>> mapList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

    while(rs.next()) {
        Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("1", rs.getString("col1"));
        map.put("2", rs.getString("col2"));
        map.put("OUTLET", rs.getString("outlet"));
        map.put("BILLDATE", rs.getString("billdate"));
        map.put("TOTAL", rs.getString("total"));
        mapList.add(map);
    }
    return mapList;
}

public static void createJson() {
    List<Map<String, String>> mapList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

    Map<String, String> map1 = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    map1.put("1", "50");
    map1.put("2", "55");
    map1.put("OUTLET", "ol2");
    map1.put("BILLDATE", "08-22-18");
    map1.put("TOTAL", "105");

    Map<String, String> map2 = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    map2.put("1", "60");
    map2.put("2", "65");
    map2.put("OUTLET", "ol3");
    map2.put("BILLDATE", "08-23-18");
    map2.put("TOTAL", "125");

    mapList.add(map1);
    mapList.add(map2);

    String json = new Gson().toJson(mapList);
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: then even that you can write them in hashmap keys just like I hardcoded. Instead of hardcoding "1" and "2" you  can write rs.getString("yourcolumnname")

Comment: Sure, let me know if you get stuck anywhere. You can run my code as it is and it will output the json string exactly as you want.

Comment: Your schema was not clear as the image you attached doesn't show all columns. If you can share the schema or even query I should be able to help you better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181997/discussion-between-manish-thakur-and-pushpesh-kumar-rajwanshi).

Answer (score 5):

Let's take a step back and try to do *everything* in SQL. MySQL can calculate grand totals using [`WITH ROLLUP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) (similar to standard SQL [`GROUPING SETS`](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/12/22/creating-a-microsoft-excel-style-pivot-table-with-grand-totals-in-sql/)), you don't need two round trips. Also, MySQL supports (to some extent) standard [SQL/JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html), so you don't have to do any formatting in Java.

#### First, let's try to write that SQL query without producing JSON:

```sql
SELECT
  CASE 

    -- The label of the grand total
    WHEN GROUPING(outlet) = 1 THEN 'TOTAL2'

    -- Prevent printing the outlet on rows 2+ per outlet group
    WHEN row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY outlet ORDER BY billdate) = 1 THEN outlet 
  END AS outlet,
  billdate,
  SUM(netAmount) AS `Total1/Ho...`,

  -- This is just a silly assumption based on your data.
  -- Your actual formula might be more involved
  SUM(CASE WHEN mod(hours, 2) = 1 THEN netAmount END) AS `1`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN mod(hours, 2) = 0 THEN netAmount END) AS `2`

  -- Possibly more?
FROM t
GROUP BY outlet, billdate WITH ROLLUP

-- Get only the grand total or ordinary groupings
HAVING GROUPING(outlet) = 1 OR GROUPING(billdate) = 0

-- Possibly add ORDER BY here to get the desired ordering if that's required
```

#### Next, let's produce JSON

For simplicity, I will not rewrite the entire query above, but put it in a CTE, which is a handy tool to structure SQL:

```sql
WITH
  t AS (
    -- Copy paste previous query here
  )
SELECT
  json_arrayagg(json_object(
     '1', t.`1`,
     '2', t.`2`,
     'OUTLET', t.outlet,
     'BILLDATE', t.billdate,
     'TOTAL', t.total
  ))
FROM t
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=86bbb9a3dcd40d89257702a682fd217c)

Note, you could also use a third party library like jOOQ, [which can export data as JSON out of the box](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/exporting/exporting-json/), or [which supports SQL/JSON functions](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/json-functions/) (disclaimer, I work for the company behind jOOQ).